# Is there a list of hidden/deleted Stockfish commands?

Tags: stockfish, uci

I have downloaded the latest version of Stockfish, and I am running it on the command line.

There is a hidden command 'd' which displays the current board.
Also, the "debug on" command is not implemented, even though it is part of the UCI protocol.

Is there a list somewhere of all commands, all "un-implemented" commands, and/or command line switches for Stockfish?

I have already downloaded and read the UCI protocol.

Before someone sugests it, I would like to write my own GUI, so downloading arena and just running it isn't an option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at the source code:

> https://github.com/official-stockfish/Stockfish/blob/master/src/uci.cpp

```
   // Additional custom non-UCI commands, mainly for debugging
      else if (token == "flip")  pos.flip();
      else if (token == "bench") bench(pos, is, states);
      else if (token == "d")     sync_cout << pos << sync_endl;
      else if (token == "eval")  sync_cout << Eval::trace(pos) << sync_endl;
```

Your "d" command is there, and others.

Answer (score 4):

I have created this gist which is the best documentation I could find - most links I found where dead

https://gist.github.com/aliostad/f4470274f39d29b788c1b09519e67372